# Giving 777 permissions to a dynamically file opened/created using open function in Perl

Tags: git, perl, file, permissions, cron

I have a Perl script, which opens a file using:

```
open(FH,">", $path);
```

But the problem is that this gives the only 644 permissions to the file(rw-r--r--). But I want to have 777 permissions to the file created dynamically. 
I am running this script from a job scheduler once a day and used **sysopen** function also but after one execution its permissions become 644 again.

Also code is pulled from the remote git repository(mainline/master branch) and this repo has 644 permissions of the file. Is this creating the problem? Changing the mode of the file to 777 and push to remote repo and then using **sysopen** function will work?

I want to make sure whats the problem, then only change any thing on mainline branch as its a critical branch.

What could be the solution?

Answer (score 1):

[sysopen](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysopen.html) can help you.

```
sysopen(FILEHANDLE, $filename, permissions, CHMOD);
```

`>>` this operator use for appending the file. It will not change the permission.

Sidenote: Always use file error handling with `die` and `$!`.